# PHPdocumentor ignores packages

Tags: php, phpdoc

My PHPdocumentor does not parse and @packages and doesn't even use the Default package correctly. It is not showing and packages on the left but does find the classes/functions.  I am running the default template.  I am running phpdoc 2.3.1 and running the following commands, both do not work:

```
phpdoc -d ./custom/ -t ./docs/api
phpdoc -d ./custom/ -t ./docs/api -defaultpackagename="test"
```

Code:

```
/**
 * This is a summary
 * 
 * This is a long description
 * 
 * @package Database
 * 
 */


/**
 * Interface DatabaseAdapterInterface
 */
interface DatabaseAdapterInterface
{
  public function connect();
  public function disconnect();
  public function query($sql);
}
```

in fact it completely ignores and comments at the beginning of the file

***EDIT

Sorry my question is is there anything that I am doing obviously wrong or why is this not parsing?

Comment: I don't see any question?

Comment: Sorry updated the question.  Asking if i am doing something wrong or why the @package does not work.  About to switch to doxygen as i am having no luck with phpdocumentor.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want that `DatabaseAdapterInterface` to appear in your `Database` package, right?  If so, then the interface element's docblock needs a `@package` tag also.